# i am getting following error when i tried to create a django project ? i am using python 3.11 with pip 23.2.1 ? Any help is appreciated

Tags: django

i am trying to create a django project but i am not able to create it.

$ django-admin startproject web
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\laupha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Users\laupha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject web': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: did you install django via pip?

Comment: share the output of command "pip list" to better understand the issue.

Comment: Please use markdown formatting for your post, because very hard to understand it as is.